# ThinApped IE10 cannot open files

Tags: pdf, adobe, ms-office, internet-explorer-10, vmware

I have managed to ThinApp Internet Explorer 10, on a Windows 7 64bits machine.

However, on the ThinApped IE10, I encountered some issues:

- When we want to open a PDF, a new tab is opened but it is empty, the PDF never shows;
- When we want to  export an Excel (xls and csv) report by clicking on a button, nothing happens. (IE9 asks if we want to open, save or cancel.)

  I tried to ThinApp together IE10 and Acrobat Reader (two entry points in one package); Acrobat Reader is launched  when new tab opens (first time 'Accept the conditions' pops up), but file still isn't displayed.

I tried to use AppLink but didn't managed to...

Would you have a process I could follow to trouble shoot this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use This :

"  width="100%" height="100%" alt="pdf"  allowscriptaccess="always"  wmode="transparent"  allowfullscreen="true" pluginspage="https://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html">